# How to update the current time and Date on each click in string

Tags: java, android, firebase, time

I'm trying to populate my child elements in firebase with current Date and Time
from following code

```
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String millisInString  = dateFormat.format(new Date());

    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name",user_name);
            map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString()+millisInString);


            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
        }
    });
```

But My problem is , it alwasy return and save the single time

for Example if I click then It will save

```
2018-04-16 10:17:54
```

and again if I click it will save the same time

```
2018-04-16 10:17:54
```

But If I restart my app and now if I click then it will save the new updated time,

2018-04-16 10:18:54

and same time again unless if I restart my app again.

Please help

Comment: Move this line inside `click` event `String millisInString  = dateFormat.format(new Date());`

Comment: because you create new date object outside the click. add this code inside of click.

Comment: I strongly recommend you store a simple number (System.currentTimeMillis()) for the date rather than a formatted string.  Format the number in your app rather than in your database.

Comment: @DougStevenson thaks for nice suggesting. I will also like to do that...I'm learning new..Hope I will be able to do that....for now everything I am learning from Tutorials and youtube so...I have no idea how to do what you have suggested.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: For storing the date and time in the database (if you need that), don’t use a naked number. It will make debugging virtually impossible since the number won’t make sense to you. Better to use the database’s built-in date and time datatypes. That’s what they are there for.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for wonderful comments. I'll consider that in my future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get  current time and Date inside `onClick()` method of your `btn_send_msg`

Try this

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String millisInString  = dateFormat.format(new Date());

        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        temp_key = root.push().getKey();
        root.updateChildren(map);

        DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map2.put("name",user_name);
        map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString()+millisInString);


        message_root.updateChildren(map2);
    }
});
```